# Derivative of the generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I was reading D.Knuth's book "Concrete mathematics. Foundation of computer science".
In chapter 8.5 Hashing was given:
$$B_n(z) = \sum_{n_1,n_2,...,n_m \geqslant \ 0 \\ n_1+n_2+...n_m = \ n } 
\begin{pmatrix}  n \\ n_1,n_2, ..., n_m    \end{pmatrix} 
z^{\begin{pmatrix} n_1 \\2   \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} n_2 \\2   \end{pmatrix} +...+\begin{pmatrix} n_m \\2   \end{pmatrix} m^{-n} } $$

We can recognize it is m-fold convolution. Indeed, if we consider the exponential super-generating function

$$G(w,z) = \sum_{n=0} B_n(z)  \frac {m^n w^n}{n!} $$

we can readily verify that $G(w,z)$ is simply an m-th power:

$$G(w,z) = \left( \sum_{k \geqslant 0} z^{\begin{pmatrix}  k \\2   \end{pmatrix}}  \frac {w^k}{k!} \right)^m $$

Take a derivative of $G(w,z)$

$$\frac d{dz}G(w,z) = \sum_{\geqslant \ 0} B_n' \frac {m^n w^n}{n!} = 
m\left( \sum_{k \geqslant \ 0} z^{\begin{pmatrix}  k \\2   \end{pmatrix}} \frac {w^k}{k!} \right)^{m-1}  \sum_{k \geqslant \ 0} \begin{pmatrix}  k \\2   \end{pmatrix} z^{\begin{pmatrix}  k \\2   \end{pmatrix} -1} \frac {w^k}{k!};  $$

The question is: What is $\sum_{k \geqslant \ 0} \begin{pmatrix}  k \\2   \end{pmatrix} z^{\begin{pmatrix}  k \\2   \end{pmatrix} -1} \frac {w^k}{k!}$ and how it appeared?

Comment: It is the chain rule $\frac{d}{dz}f(z)^m = mf(z)^{m-1}\frac{d}{dz}f(z)$.